# SSMS Short cut to actually getting to a query window so I can write code

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have to do this task all the time for several different database servers multiple times a day.

1. Open SSMS
2. Connect to a server (with a saved password)
3. Click through databases
4. Open a query window for the desired database

Is there a shortcut I can use to do all of this for me with one click?

Alternatively, is there a way I can save a "solution" that has connections to all the databases I use.

Comment: why not just leave SSMS open, CTRL+N to get a new window, and right click to change the connection if it's not the DB you want?

Answer (score 3):

In the registered servers pane you can right-click any group and open a query window. The new query window will execute the T-SQL on all servers in that group.

[image]

In your T-SQL script add

> USE MyDatabaseName
>
> GO

Comment: Looks like you can select the default db in the connection properties when registering a server.

Comment: @MicahBurnett you can certainly do that. but then u have to modify all your connections, or you can simply add that one line tot he script. your preference.,

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest a combination of [Registered Servers](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173574(v=sql.105).aspx) and T-SQL.

**Registered Servers:** Open up the Registered Servers panel in SSMS (<kbd>Ctrl+Alt+G</kbd> or View -> Registered Servers) and under Database Engine -> Local Server Groups, add connections for each of the servers you access on a regular basis. You can even create folders within this view to organize your connections (although you can't move them around except by Powershell).

When you need to execute a query, go to the server in Registered Servers, right-click, and select New Query.

**T-SQL:** Rather than navigate a slow tree structure to find the database you want, run `USE DATABASENAME;` as your first query in that query window. It'll switch the context for that window to the specified database.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
ssms.exe -S SERVERNAME -d DATABASENAME -E
```

I should add, you will still be prompted for your password and the object explorer remains pointed to the top